# Access API through FireWall

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

I have an API (A) that behind the company fire wall and another api (B) that is public facing.
How would I allow API A and B to communicate?

Thank you

Comment: You can set in firewall the ip and port of api(B) is allowed.

Comment: You need to setup an access rule on the fire wall and setup a DMZ for your public api.